# I want to add this function in sql in a Postgresql Database

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, plpgsql

I have written this function:

```
create function check_same_price() returns integer as $result$
declare
 result integer;
begin
 set res = (select *
  from (select count(distinct title), price_dvd_buy
  from dvd_to_buy
  group by price_dvd_buy) as dummy
  where count>1);
if (res==none) then result=0;
else result=1;
end if;
end;
$result$ language plpgsql;
```

the function returns 0 if there is the same price for same title, otherwise it returns 1.
This check is done because I want the same price for the same film;
I'm using phppgadmin to manage it.
I receive this error:

```
SQL error:

ERROR:  error of sintax to or near "("
LINE 5:  set res = (select *
```

What's wrong, I don't know to fix it. Thanks!

Comment: There is no `set` in PL/pgSQL. Please read the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW

Answer (score 1):

```
create function check_same_price()
returns boolean as $$
begin
   return exists(select count(distinct title)
                    from dvd_to_buy
                   group by price_dvd_buy
                   having count(distinct title) > 1)
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```